# Change button style on the fly in Win32

Tags: c++, winapi

Below is part of a working normal win32 application created from scratch, not dialog based. it will show the text on the buttom, not top:

```
hButtonApply = CreateWindow(
    "BUTTON",
    "Reset",
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON | BS_BOTTOM,
    95, 130, 120, 40, 
    hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON_RESET, hInstance, NULL);
SendMessage(hButtonApply, BM_SETSTYLE, BS_TOP, TRUE);
```

this however makes it a radio button:

```
SendMessage(hButtonApply, BM_SETSTYLE, BS_RADIOBUTTON, TRUE);
```

same for a resource-defined dialog button control.

Subclassing is acceptable. Owner-Drawn Buttons are not acceptable. Thanks, Haotian Yang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some window styles can only be set during CreateWindow, I guess this might be one of them.

Did you try SetWindowLong ?

**Edit:**

This seems to work:

```
LONG style = GetWindowLong(hBtn,GWL_STYLE);
style = (style & ~BS_BOTTOM) | BS_TOP;
SetWindowLong(hBtn,GWL_STYLE,style);
```